# PHP: how to delete/remove a key from an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

In PHP: how do I delete/remove a key from an array?

In my PHP script, I process the value(s) of an input form.  If a value does not meet a certain condition, then I create an array to store the value.  Later on in the script, if the value meets a 2nd condition, then I want to remove the key and the value from the array.  The reason I want to remove the key, in addition to the value it holds, is because if there is any/another key in the array, then I will pass the array to a function that will work on each key and value in that array.

I have tried `unset()` which does not work for me, because it only unsets the value of the key, not the key itself.

I have thought of creating another array that contains only values that do not meet the 2nd condition, but I do not want to do that if I can delete the particular key(s) in the array.

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{   
    if($field == "HiddenConditionsEditProcess")
    {
        if(is_numeric($value))
        {
            $GoodData[$field] = $value;
        }
    }
    elseif(
    ($field == "NameSanskrit")
    ||
    ($field == "NameWestern"))
    {
        if(!(preg_match("[[a-zA-z +'-]+]",$value)))
        {
            $ErrorArray[] = $field;

            $GoodData[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));
        }
        else
        {
            $GoodData[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, strip_tags(trim($value)));
        }
    }
}

if(
(isset($ErrorArray['NameSanskrit']))
&&
(!(isset($ErrorArray['NameWestern']))))
{
    unset($ErrorArray['NameSanskrit']);
}

DisplayError($GoodData, $ErrorArray, "ConditionsEdit.php");
```

Comment: explain more on concrete example .

Comment: I think you got it wrong. unset() destroys array element which means there's no key nor value left.

Comment: @ArekGorecki. You are correct, I had misunderstood the behaviour of unset() and, therefore, was misusing it.  Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) - does exactly what you expect it to do, that is remove the element overall, the key and value.

```js
<?php
function foo() 
{
    unset($GLOBALS['bar']);
}

$bar = "something";
foo();
?>
```

Based on your script the $ErrorArray never gets a key "NameSanskrit" which you're trying to unset. Because you're doing this $ErrorArray[] <-- your key will be numeric.